# Managing Database Schema/Data with multiple developers when the applications manages the database

Tags: database, version-control, sugarcrm, suitecrm

So this can't be a new problem.

We are developing a solution making use of an open source CRM (SuiteCRM).  Our solution will require quite a lot of customisation both in CRM configuration and custom code.  We will have 4 or 5 developers with any one of them making required configuration changes to the CRM.  The CRM manages it's own DB and dynamically modifies the schema and configuration data without even notifying the developer in question that this has been done.

Unmanaged we will end up with 4 or 5 different versions of the database to merge.

Liquibase may be an option, but filtering out test data from schema and config changes might be a nightmare.

I thought I would reach out and see if anyone has come across this kind of problem before.

Comment: what type of database changes they made?

Answer (score 0):

Once method is to have your developers create/update database dumps into the root of your project before committing there changes to a CVS repository.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I have considered this.  It may be the only option, however I am not yet sure of how much 'data' change will occur.  I think the schema changes will be small and rare, but I don't want to have to merge data.  Not only will developers have test data which will be different between environments, but I'm fairly sure the webapp store important configuration data in the DB too, so we might not be able to avoid doing schema and data dumps.